# How do I use matplotlib.patch?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, patch

I got a set of elements, each element has four node (points). I want to use patch it as it can be done in MATLAB. I tried to find an example of matplotlib.patch but I could not find any. Does anyone have an example of matplotlib.patch ?

Thx

Comment: There is no `matplotlib.patch`. Do you mean [`matplotlib.patches`](https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html)? Which one of those do you want to use, and what is the problem? Or, maybe you just tell what you want to achieve in general.

Answer (score -1):

After looking into what patches in MATLAB are I think I found what you are looking for. There is quite an extensive code snippet over at the matplotlib documentation that will help you: [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/patch_collection.html)